# Store rows from repeating table in InfoPath 2010 form library form in secondary SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a requirement to take each row of a specific repeating table in a Form Library form created in InfoPath 2010 and store them as individual rows in a SharePoint 2013 list other than the Form Library, but located within the same site.  The form should also be able to display the repeating table correctly on subsequent viewings by a user.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating new fields in InfoPath to store the merged values of each column in the repeating table using the following XPath format:

```
xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(../my:LocationGroup/my:Location, 'concat(my:City, ";")'), "..")
```

I then promoted these fields to the SharePoint form library, and then used a Nintex workflow to split these fields and store the values in collection variables. Then I used a For Each loop to create a new row in another SharePoint list to contain each item in the collection variables. Works like a charm.